# After Quarkus 2.x -> 3.3.3 upgrade, tons of "Class does not exist in Classloader warnings"

Tags: quarkus

We have a decently large Quarkus app with minimal dependencies. I'm working on the upgrade from Quarkus 2.7 to Quarkus 3.3.3.

I used the `quarkus update` command and was able to get the app up and running after a few minimal changes.

The app starts up fine, but we get tons of warnings regarding classes in jakarta.jms similar to this:

```
Failed to index jakarta.jms.XAConnection: Class does not exist in ClassLoader
...
Unable to properly register the hierarchy of the following classes for reflection as they are not in the Jandex index:
    - io.mashona.logwriting.ArrayStore (source: ResteasyReactiveProcessor > blah.MyResource[AnotherResource getAnotherResource(java.lang.String aStr)])
    - jakarta.jms.BytesMessage (source: ResteasyReactiveProcessor > blah.MyResource[AnotherResource getAnotherResource(java.lang.String aStr)])
```

I did a dependency report and I cannot see jakarta.jms being included. There's no direct references to jakarta.jms in our source code. And our codebase has very few dependencies outside of Quarkus. I'm not really sure how to proceed with removing these warnings. Any ideas?

The full set of warnings is below (though I've obfuscated our package/class/method names).

```
Failed to index jakarta.jms.XAConnection: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader: DEV@1eb5174b
Failed to index jakarta.jms.XASession: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader: DEV@1eb5174b
Failed to index jakarta.jms.XAConnectionFactory: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader: DEV@1eb5174b
Failed to index jakarta.jms.Connection: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader: DEV@1eb5174b
Failed to index org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.Journal: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader: DEV@1eb5174b
Failed to index jakarta.jms.Session: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader: DEV@1eb5174b
Failed to index jakarta.jms.ExceptionListener: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader: DEV@1eb5174b
Failed to index jakarta.jms.ConnectionMetaData: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader: DEV@1eb5174b
Failed to index io.mashona.logwriting.ArrayStore: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader: DEV@1eb5174b
Failed to index jakarta.jms.BytesMessage: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader: DEV@1eb5174b
Failed to index jakarta.jms.MapMessage: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader: DEV@1eb5174b
Failed to index jakarta.jms.Message: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader: DEV@1eb5174b
Failed to index jakarta.jms.ObjectMessage: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader: DEV@1eb5174b
Failed to index jakarta.jms.StreamMessage: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader: DEV@1eb5174b
Failed to index jakarta.jms.TemporaryQueue: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader: DEV@1eb5174b
Failed to index jakarta.jms.TemporaryTopic: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader: DEV@1eb5174b
Failed to index jakarta.jms.TextMessage: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader: DEV@1eb5174b
Failed to index jakarta.jms.MessageListener: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader: DEV@1eb5174b
Failed to index org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.RecordInfo: Class does not exist in ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Deployment Class Loader: DEV@1eb5174b
(build-40) Unable to properly register the hierarchy of the following classes for reflection as they are not in the Jandex index:
    - io.mashona.logwriting.ArrayStore (source: ResteasyReactiveProcessor > blah.MyResource[AnotherResource getAnotherResource(java.lang.String aStr)])
    - jakarta.jms.BytesMessage (source: ResteasyReactiveProcessor > blah.MyResource[AnotherResource getAnotherResource(java.lang.String aStr)])
    - jakarta.jms.Connection (source: ResteasyReactiveProcessor > blah.MyResource[AnotherResource getAnotherResource(java.lang.String aStr)])
    - jakarta.jms.ConnectionMetaData (source: ResteasyReactiveProcessor > blah.MyResource[AnotherResource getAnotherResource(java.lang.String aStr)])
    - jakarta.jms.ExceptionListener (source: ResteasyReactiveProcessor > blah.MyResource[AnotherResource getAnotherResource(java.lang.String aStr)])
    - jakarta.jms.MapMessage (source: ResteasyReactiveProcessor > blah.MyResource[AnotherResource getAnotherResource(java.lang.String aStr)])
    - jakarta.jms.Message (source: ResteasyReactiveProcessor > blah.MyResource[AnotherResource getAnotherResource(java.lang.String aStr)])
    - jakarta.jms.MessageListener (source: ResteasyReactiveProcessor > blah.MyResource[AnotherResource getAnotherResource(java.lang.String aStr)])
    - jakarta.jms.ObjectMessage (source: ResteasyReactiveProcessor > blah.MyResource[AnotherResource getAnotherResource(java.lang.String aStr)])
    - jakarta.jms.Session (source: ResteasyReactiveProcessor > blah.MyResource[AnotherResource getAnotherResource(java.lang.String aStr)])
    - jakarta.jms.StreamMessage (source: ResteasyReactiveProcessor > blah.MyResource[AnotherResource getAnotherResource(java.lang.String aStr)])
    - jakarta.jms.TemporaryQueue (source: ResteasyReactiveProcessor > blah.MyResource[AnotherResource getAnotherResource(java.lang.String aStr)])
    - jakarta.jms.TemporaryTopic (source: ResteasyReactiveProcessor > blah.MyResource[AnotherResource getAnotherResource(java.lang.String aStr)])
    - jakarta.jms.TextMessage (source: ResteasyReactiveProcessor > blah.MyResource[AnotherResource getAnotherResource(java.lang.String aStr)])
    - jakarta.jms.XAConnection (source: ResteasyReactiveProcessor > blah.MyResource[AnotherResource getAnotherResource(java.lang.String aStr)])
    - jakarta.jms.XAConnectionFactory (source: ResteasyReactiveProcessor > blah.MyResource[AnotherResource getAnotherResource(java.lang.String aStr)])
    - jakarta.jms.XASession (source: ResteasyReactiveProcessor > blah.MyResource[AnotherResource getAnotherResource(java.lang.String aStr)])
    - org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.Journal (source: ResteasyReactiveProcessor > blah.MyResource[AnotherResource getAnotherResource(java.lang.String aStr)])
    - org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.RecordInfo (source: ResteasyReactiveProcessor > blah.MyResource[AnotherResource getAnotherResource(java.lang.String aStr)])
Consider adding them to the index either by creating a Jandex index for your dependency via the Maven plugin, an empty META-INF/beans.xml or quarkus.index-dependency properties.
```

Comment: This sounds like a bug or at the very least a user experience issue, Mind opening an issue on our Github repo?

Comment: @geoand thanks for fixing that bug so quickly!